# maniplate html sent from server

Tags: html, client-side

Is is possible, on the client side, to manipulate the HTML sent from a site when you are not the owner of the site, and have no access to the code?

Comment: Simplest way I can think of is in Firefox, right-click and select _Inspect Element_, then in the "Inspector" you can edit HTML on the fly. Of course you're the only one to see those changes, and reloading or navigating away from the page will reset the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There are many ways.

HTTP proxies such as [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Burp](http://portswigger.net/burp/download.html) can break on all requests and then manipulate the response before it reaches the browser.

[Video explaining how this is done in Fiddler.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bo5kXMAcV0)

There are also several browser plugins like [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) (Chrome) and [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) (Firefox) that allow you to execute custom JavaScript on page load automatically.

Answer (score 0):

There are built-in DOM manipulation extensions for all browsers, like this one : 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/